# Django - unable to load static files?

Tags: django

Very new to Django I am trying to follow along a tutorial by sentdex over on youtube.

> Django version 1.9

Chose this version as that is being used in the tutorial.

I can't seem to figure out how to get the `css` file to load.

The location of the `css` file

`/media/xxx/django tutorial/mysite/personal/static/personal/css`

I assume the `BASE_URL` is referencing till: 
`/media/xxx/djangotutroial/mysite`

This is the location of the `manage.py`. Or am I wrong?

The `css` file is reference in `header.html`:

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
```

I read through a lot of the answers and if I understand correctly I have to change `settings.py` in `mysite` folder.

This is what I have at the moment:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'personal'),
]
```

I have tried a lot of combinations in the `os.path.join` I still can't get the file to load.

Thank for your help.

Project Structure:

```
django tutorial
--mysite
  --mysite
    ---------__pycache_
    ---------__init__.py
    ---------settings.py
    ---------urls.py
    ---------wsgi.py
  --personal
    ---------migrations
    ---------__pycache_
    ---------static
             ------personal
                   ------css     # has the bootstrap.min.css
                   ------js
    ---------templates
    ---------admin.py
    ---------apps.py
    ---------init.py
    ---------models.py
    ---------tests.py
    ---------urls.py
    ---------views.py
```

If someone can tell me the right command to get the directory structure in ubuntu I would be happy to show that here.

Template:

In home.html:

```
{% extends "personal/header.html" %}


{% block content %}


<p>Hey, welcome to my webpage. We are testing.<p>


{% include "personal/includes/htmlsnippets.html" %}

{% endblock %}
```

Error message in view page source

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Page not found at /static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    table { border:none; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; }
    td, th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-right:.5em; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ol { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info ol li { font-family: monospace; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="summary">
    <h1>Page not found <span>(404)</span></h1>
    <table class="meta">
      <tr>
        <th>Request Method:</th>
        <td>GET</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Request URL:</th>
        <td>http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
  <div id="info">

      <p>&#39;personal/css/bootstrap.min.css&#39; could not be found</p>

  </div>

  <div id="explanation">
    <p>
      You're seeing this error because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in
      your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>, and     Django
      will display a standard 404 page.
    </p>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

In the terminal where runserver:

```
[24/Feb/2019 06:19:32] "GET /static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1703
```

Error when running using @bkawan code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>Page not found at /static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css</title>
  <meta name="robots" content="NONE,NOARCHIVE">
  <style type="text/css">
    html * { padding:0; margin:0; }
    body * { padding:10px 20px; }
    body * * { padding:0; }
    body { font:small sans-serif; background:#eee; }
    body>div { border-bottom:1px solid #ddd; }
    h1 { font-weight:normal; margin-bottom:.4em; }
    h1 span { font-size:60%; color:#666; font-weight:normal; }
    table { border:none; border-collapse: collapse; width:100%; }
    td, th { vertical-align:top; padding:2px 3px; }
    th { width:12em; text-align:right; color:#666; padding-    right:.5em; }
    #info { background:#f6f6f6; }
    #info ol { margin: 0.5em 4em; }
    #info ol li { font-family: monospace; }
    #summary { background: #ffc; }
    #explanation { background:#eee; border-bottom: 0px none; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="summary">
    <h1>Page not found <span>(404)</span></h1>
    <table class="meta">
      <tr>
        <th>Request Method:</th>
        <td>GET</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th>Request URL:</th>
           <td>http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
  </div>
 <div id="info">

      <p>&#39;personal/css/bootstrap.min.css&#39; could not be found</p>

  </div>

  <div id="explanation">
    <p>
      You're seeing this error because you have <code>DEBUG = True</code> in
      your Django settings file. Change that to <code>False</code>,     and Django
          will display a standard 404 page.
        </p>
      </div>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: What error did you receive when loading page?

Comment: @Devang Padhiyar >Page not found at /personal/static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css I have tried a bunch of combinations and the error(404) is always page not found when I look at the page source and check the link to the css file with different paths.

Comment: Could you please share project structure (tree)?

Comment: @DevangPadhiyar trying to figure out how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please check if you have done first step as below

Official Documentation link for Django 1.9 [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/)

> This document is for an insecure version of Django that is no longer
>   supported. Please upgrade to a newer release!

*Try to move on new release since documentation 1.9 is no longer supported.*

**Configuring static files**

1. Make sure that django.contrib.staticfiles is included in your INSTALLED_APPS.

**Check If your folder structure is similar as below**

[Project Structure image Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dLtSJ.png)

You do not need to add code below unless if personal folder is same level as BASE_DIR

```
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'personal')
```

Your code below is fine if you have personal app and then static folder inside personal app and then personal folder inside static folder ie personal/static/personal

```
 {% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
```

#### In Case if Page not found error.

Check if bootstrap.min.css exists in path personal/css/bootstrap.min.css
 Check **spelling** as well.

#### Check your app ie personal in this case is included in INSTALLED_APPS

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'personal'
]
```

Comment: If it does not work please share your template code. May be you are doing wrong in template.

Comment: django.contrib.staticfiles is included in INSTALLED_APPS. I am adding the project structure in the main question.

Comment: please have a look.

Comment: Can you share code in template as well? I mean are you trying to use something like {% extends 'header.html' %}.  Please share ERROR message as well.

Comment: I have added it above. I am seeing the error message through view page source.

Comment: Your code seems to be fine. Please check the spelling of bootstrap.min.css inside css.   <title>Page not found at /static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css</title>
This means you do not have this particular file inside css

Comment: I copied the filename: `bootstrap.min.css` path: `/media/xxx/django tutorial/mysite/personal/static/personal/css`. In the mysite--> settings `STATIC_URL = '/static/'
#STATICFILES_DIRS = ('/personal/static',)
#STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),]
#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR), 'personal','static')
` Double checked the spelling in `header.html` `{% load staticfiles %}
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'personal/css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>` I just can't seem to figure this out.

Comment: please share your views.py code as well.
this must be something like raised by. 
 <tr>
        <th>Request URL:</th>
        <td>http://localhost:8000/static/personal/css/bootstrap.min.css</td>
      </tr>
      
      <tr>
        <th>Raised by:</th>
        <td>personal.views.HomePage</td>
      </tr>

Comment: views.py(location: `/media/sid1/django tutorial/mysite/personal`) code: `from django.shortcuts import render

# Create your views here.

def index(request):
    return render(request,'personal/home.html')` Thank you for all the help.

Comment: Please check this repo small working demo I have created [link](https://gitlab.com/bkawan/django-static-files-1.9.git)

Go through all the files one by one

Comment: Made the changes and now it shows this. Cant give the full trace in comment.

  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/media/sid1/django tutorial/mysite/mysite/urls.py", line 22, in <module>
    url(r'^$', views.HomePage.as_view()),
AttributeError: module 'personal.views' has no attribute 'HomePage'

Comment: you are missing HomePage class in personal/views.py
[link](https://gitlab.com/bkawan/django-static-files-1.9/blob/master/mysite/personal/views.py)

Comment: Still the 404 missing error. adding it to question.

Comment: clone my repo and try it.

Comment: Hmmm..when I clone it, the page loads the css file. Thanks. I need to figure out what I am doing wrong otherwise I will not be able to add more stuff.

Comment: Found the problem, INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py didn't have my app in there. Thank you so much for the help.

Answer (score 2):

You should serve them during development. Check this [part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development). 
Edit your main `urls.py`(you'll find it in same folder as `settings.py`).

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Make sure that your app is listed in `INSTALLED_APPS` in django settings.

Comment: Thanks Davit, but where do I add this code? In the settings file?

Comment: Read the docs but I would still like to understand why I can't load the file in the current setup/Where I am going wrong.

Comment: In main `urls.py`.

Comment: Davit, I added the STATICFILES_DIRS still shows the same error. I have added the directory structure. If you wouldn't mind having a look. Thanks

Comment: Thanks. The base of the problem was that INSTALLED_APPS in settings.py didn't have my app listed. Now that I have added it there everything runs. Thank you so much.

Comment: Glad to hear that.

Comment: Please post it in your answer and I can accept it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Remove */personal* from your style sheet import. Instead, just have:

```
{%load static%}
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/bootstrap.min.css' %}" type = "text/css"/>
```

Comment: Thanks sagar. No change even when I made that change. Still getting the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you copied and pasted exactly the same code but the p closing tag is out of syntax in home.html.