# Django any installed app not finding static files

Tags: django, static-files

latest versions of Django and Python, MacOS, PyCharm

I am having trouble installing any app. Everytime I try, it does not find the resources. Currently, I'm attempting to install uncaught in my Django app.

My app's name is RealEstate.

Deployment Directory for static: project_name/app_name/static/

Directory I use to copy new or revised files to Deployment Directory with collectstatic:
project_name/app_name/static_changes/

inside static, I have an admin folder with different subfolders:
static/admin/css, static/admin/fonts, static/admin/img, static/admin/js, static/admin/node_modules

settings.py:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))

DEBUG = TRUE

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'RealEstate/static')
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "RealEstate/static_changes/"),
]
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

I have run the install for uncaught, which created a package-lock.json file and a node_modules folder with the uncaught resources, both put into the root of my project:

```
$ npm install --save uncaught
```

Since I use static_changes to copy any new or modified resources into the deployment directory static, I have copied the node_modules folder put into the project root to my app_name/static_changes/admin folder and run collectstatic

```
python3.7 manage.py collectstatic
```

It copies the files to app_name/static. But when I open the browser, the files are never found, and I get this message in the Run Console:

```
Not Found: /admin/node_modules/uncaught/lib/index.js
[26/Feb/2019 22:57:47] "GET /admin/node_modules/uncaught/lib/index.js
HTTP/1.1" 404 14044
```

I have tried moving admin/node_modules to every part of my directory structure and run collectstatic to it, and the app still never finds the resources.

Please help. Why is it that any app I try to install, it cannot see the resources, even though they exist in project_name/app_name/static/admin and I used collectstatic to get it there?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54842511/5840704

Comment: doesn't work. Still looking for a solution

Comment: @DavitTovmasyan I solved the problem. It was the src in html having the wrong URL. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

make sure that the URL in base.html is correct, like this:

```
<script src="{% static "admin/node_modules/uncaught/lib/index.js" %}"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

In macOS, I followed these steps:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/

And ended like this:

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent  ---> Didn't touch this specific line

STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / "static"
]
```

main.html

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static '/css/main.css' %}">
```