# Django static file 404 not found

Tags: django

I have searched the similar questions but did not find my answer.

My simple webapp structure is:

```
mysite/
    manage.py
    mysite/
        __init__.py
        settings.py
        urls.py
        wsgi.py
    static/
        test.txt
    myfirstapp/
```

I have set STATIC_URL = '/static/'
and STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")

and when I start the django server, I print the static path out which is
/home/pi/mysite/static, looks correct

In my template, the code is:

```
{% load static %}
<li><a href="{% static 'test.txt' %}">Test File</a></li>
```

If I click the link, I always got 404. However, if I put the static folder in /home/pi/mysite/mysite/, then the static dir is /home/pi/mysite/mysite/static, this code can work and I can view the txt file.

I am confused by the settings, and I thought I set the static directory in settings in the root directory but not in the "mysite/mysite". Why the real behavior is opposite? What is the problem here? Thanks!

Comment: Have you checked you have **test.txt**  inside static folder

Comment: Yes it is there. The problem is that I have to put the static directory in mysite/mysite

Comment: Check if  it helps which I have answered similar question. [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54842384/django-unable-to-load-static-files/54844612#54844612)

Answer (score 2):

You should serve them during development. Check this [part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development). 
Edit your main `urls.py`(you'll find it in same folder as `settings.py`).

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

Answer (score 0):

1. you need run `python manage.py collectstatic` on your server.
   This will place the static file in the location of STATIC_URL
2. You need to configure static files in your web server

for instance, Nginx conf file:

```
location /static/ {     
  root   /django_path/static/;    
}
```

Comment: Im just using the django development server. I have run python manage.py collectstatic

Comment: Also didn't work for me...